# Nuxt TypeScript error: nuxt:typescript Cannot find module '@/my-module'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tsconfig

I have setup Nuxt with TypeScript using the instructions from https://typescript.nuxt.org. The transition was pretty seamless and ok, except that I can't get rid of this error that `nuxt:typescript` "Cannot find module", which obviously is a false-positive.

My imports look like this:

```
import InputField from '@/components/InputField.vue'
```

I have tried with `~/` and without the `.vue` extension. Nothing works.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["esnext", "esnext.asynciterable", "dom"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"],
      "~*": ["src/*"],
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "types": ["@types/node", "@nuxt/types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And I have this object in my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
typescript: {
  typeCheck: {
    eslint: true,
    vue: true
  }
}
```

[image: Error example]

Comment: Try to change to 
"@/*": ["./src/*"]

Comment: @Aldarund sadly, that didn't help.

Comment: create a minimal reproduction on github please

Comment: There's a fix here, but it only covers `.vue` files, and not `.ts` file imports: https://github.com/nuxt/typescript/issues/153

Comment: ye, thats right, didnt know u dont have it :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/nuxt/typescript/issues/153#issuecomment-543010838

Basically, create a `ts-shim.d.ts` in your root directory with these contents:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue
}
```

As for your `tsconfig.json`, make sure you have these entries in there:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This solved my problems with both `.vue` imports and `.ts` imports.

**Note!** It is now absolutely mandatory to include *.vue* at the end of your Vue imports, otherwise the imports will fail:

```
import SomeComponent from '~/components/SomeComponent.vue'
```

Comment: "It is now absolutely mandatory to include .vue " helped me thanks